# Can I transform arrays into RegEx form?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to run this code, which the goal is to alert the temperature of the city if they are contained in the array.
I was trying to use the function *search*, but I understand that it only works with RegEx.
My doubt is if there is a way to transform the objects into RegEx?

```js
let weather = {
  "paris": {
    temp: 19.7,
    humidity: 80
  },
  "tokyo": {
    temp: 17.3,
    humidity: 50
  },
  "lisbon": {
    temp: 30.2,
    humidity: 20
  },
  "san francisco": {
    temp: 20.9,
    humidity: 100
  },
  "moscow": {
    temp: -5,
    humidity: 20
  }
};


let city = prompt("Please, enter a city");
console.log(weather[city].temp);

function citySearch() {
    let result = city.search(weather);
    console.log(result);
    if (result === -1)
 {
     alert("Ain't no city here");
 } else {
     alert("EUREKAA!!!");
 } }
citySearch();
```

Comment: First 2 lines: `let city = prompt("Please, enter a city");console.log(weather[city].temp);` that tells the temperature of the city if its in the list, or it errors if `weather[city]` is `undefined`. I would focus on expanding on that for your citySearch implementation

Comment: Regex searches through a string, so you'd have to convert your weather object into a string. To answer your question, yes, you can transform anything into a string representation and then search through it with regex, but in this example I agree with @chiliNUT and suggest not doing it here. I don't see the benefit of doing it that way.